# Constrain TypeScript generic to a key of a property of another generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following interfaces and object set up:

```
interface ServicesList {
    [key: string]: Service;
}

interface Service {
    uuid: string;
    characteristics: CharacteristictList;
}

interface CharacteristictList {
    [key: string]: string;
}

const ServiceAndCharacteristicMap: ServicesList = {
    firstService: {
        uuid: '0x100',
        characteristics: {
            characteristicOne: '0x0101',
        },
    },
    secondService: {
        uuid: '0x200',
        characteristics: {
            secondCharacteristic: '0x0201'
        }
    }
};
```

Then, I have the following function defined:

```
function sendCharacteristic<T extends Service, K extends keyof T['characteristics']>(props: {
        service: T;
        characteristic: K;
    }) {
        console.log(props.service.uuid, 
                    props.service.characteristics[props.characteristic])
}
```

Currently, TypeScript complains about this with the following compile-time error:

> Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'CharacteristictList'

My goal is to constrain the second parameter (`characteristic`) so that I have type safety for which keys I use. For example, the following should succeed:

```
//should succeed
sendCharacteristic({
    service: ServiceAndCharacteristicMap.firstService,
    characteristic: 'characteristicOne'
});
```

But, this should fail, since `characteristicOne` belongs to `firstService` and I'm passing `secondService` for the first parameter:

```
//should fail since characteristicOne belongs to firstService
sendCharacteristic({
    service: ServiceAndCharacteristicMap.secondService,
    characteristic: 'characteristicOne'
});
```

Right now, neither of the two call sites for `sendCharacteristic` complain about compilation errors.

**How can I correctly constrain the `characteristic` parameter so that I get type safety for the particular instance of `Service` that I'm passing in?**

[TypeScript playground with all included code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrQG7CQZwDLA5jIDeAUMpcgNoDWEAngFzJFSgDmAui+lFkgDcZAL5kyoSLEQo+AlOSrIArsuAATFm07ClCABZwoiKYTDYcLAMKHjCU0WxgCRYWInho8JMhtGT0GZOLsSKVHSMWmDsINxRMRxu4ggA9iBEaJjYEACCIOp+dg7mCACycAAOvFm4IcgAvKQUVDDAUERy2SxhSpSqGiwA5AAMAB4AjMPDgwA0zb3IBv72gY4Ilk0LC0tFqyUA8iAQQ2PDk+Oz870ic0o3VzgQqfmdSN1XSv2ayCOjAExTS5bRa2ALsNYbHrA1hPNIFUErcElE6jYYAi4fKhiO6iYRkGDKED2YBpGH5QpgoIIAA8ABVkBBRpB8jhMvxsjNkABpBlMiAs5D0BgpGDIWnUQY7SkQwZcAB8AAoKlAUhVIZjKI92W8xbotlLEVSWFy9ZQRABKTb6tI4FIAGwgADo7SkOEqVWrHVr5I6vpzlaqcF6ak6DcULNQA56w3tsFxzaJxAB6JM4fQpZR29SsZQIJAQdRkR7khHhhAKqHerps+R5eHLMvlCqO1rtMCvCC3KgxpHYIY9qmHCCDUTmvEptMZrPIeDAO2sUA+AdrIfIABGEBdsVZYBSM7aHRDRf59d2vfLlZD1W1uRLDdjZUqwee6g7Xcoy+RP0-2CHI4tghAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with the code is that you are nor preserving the type of the constant you are assigning to `ServiceAndCharacteristicMap`

If you completely remove the annotation, the code works as expected.  [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrQG7CQZwDLA5jIDeAUMpcgNoDWEAngFzJFSgDmAui+lFkgDcZAL5kyoSLEQo+AlOSrIArsuAATFm07ClCABZwoiKYTDYcLAMKHjCU0WxgCRYWInho8JMhtGT0GZOLsSKVHSMWmDsINxRMRxu4ggA9iBEaJjYEACCIOp+dg7mCACycAAOyAC8pBRUMMBQRHLZLGFKlKoaLADkAAwAHgCM-f29ADT1ncgG-vaBjgiWdTMzc0WLJQDyIBB9Q-2jw5PTnSJTShdnOBCp+a1I7WdK3ZrIA4MATGOna7O2ALsJYrDr-Vh3NIFQELYElA6Dfo-E4vKhiK6iYRkGDKED2YBpCH5QpAoIIAA8ABVkBBBpB8jhMvxshNkABpGl0iAM5D0BgpGDISnUXobUkg3pcZAAMlY0U4AD4ABQVKApCqg1GUW7Mp5C3RrMWwsksNkGygiACUq0NaRwKQANhAAHQOlIcFVqjXOnXyZ1vVmq9U4H1ZJDOo3FCzUIPeyNbbBcS2icQAelTOH0KWUDvUrGUCCQEHUZFuxJhUYQSrBvraTPkeWh80r5QqzsazTAjwglyo8bh2D6-bJuwgvVElqx6cz2dzyHgwAdrFAPmHS1HyAARhA3bFGWAUvOmi0wxBS9ym5sB1Wa6feKfGyTjUtW6H7upu73KGv4R8f9hR3HK1BCAA)

You could also use a function to constrain `ServiceAndCharacteristicMap` to be `ServicesList` while preserving the type

```
function makeServicesList<T extends ServicesList>(o: T){
    return o;
}

const ServiceAndCharacteristicMap = makeServicesList({
    firstService: {
        uuid: '0x100',
        characteristics: {
            characteristicOne: '0x0101',
        },
    },
    secondService: {
        uuid: '0x200',
        characteristics: {
            secondCharacteristic: '0x0201'
        }
    }
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMrQG7CQZwDLA5jIDeAUMpcgNoDWEAngFzJFSgDmAui+lFkgDcZAL5kyoSLEQo+AlOSrIArsuAATFm07ClCABZwoiKYTDYcLAMKHjCU0WxgCRYWInho8JMhtGT0GZOLsSKVHSMWmDsINxRMRxu4jDKIPbAAPYgyAC2cPRy2BD4ZgA8ACrIEAAekCDqOGiYRSVEAHwAFBks5QCUYZRQEGDKUNkZSWQIWURN-EUAgvV+dg7mCACycAAOyAC8ufkQhbghHQPIMMBQRCcQLBdKqhosAOQADNUAjO-vrwA0FCUVAM-nsgUcCEspCBwOBoNWEPWAHkQPdkB9qu8fl8AbDgSJAUpCficBBpvU7g98U81JoMZ8AEy-PFwygIgLsSHQx5sskU9QrTlBBBvT7vZm4mlUMTE0S9YRkFJpcxZVgQZa2YWQipVWoahpzeT-ZAAaT1dUN9AYGRgyHK1FeHPBXPWOFeXGQADJWNFOJ1tlAMtsedLKGT5kgero2c61tgWKaY5QRL0YWzkBScBkADYQAB0OYyHA6geDOHzEfk+ee6hNZZDleaSHzcaRFmoDYrbdd2C4vVE4gA9EOcPoMsoc+pWMoEEgIOoyGTNWD4whzqTm+i7ktBVqXSKttt81cbmA7kSQfu128eyLURBXvLFSOxxOp5c4MAc6xQD475CD7IAARhARaxI0YAZJc1y3FuS4GkKB6QhuShVkUvBbruSFrkeTYChe+IAest7Xu2CAPk+qaCEAA)